# NSMutableArray initwithcapacity value always coming "0"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

My code is the following one:

```
int totalBarCount = 12;
NSMutableArray *tmpValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:totalBarCount];
[tmpValue addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tmpToplam]];

NSLog (@"%f",[tmpValue count]);
```

`[tmpValue count]` always returns 0. Why? How can I get 12?

Comment: Ignore `initWithCapacity:`;  it doesn't do what you think and doesn't really offer any useful performance advantage in all but the very rarest of cases.   NSArray/NSMutableArray do not support "holes".

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
NSLog (@"%d", [tmpValue count]);
```

This will give you the count of items in the array, which is 1.

You won't get 12 from -count; 12 is the capacity of the array, i.e. the amount it could potentially hold before needing to reallocate its storage.

You're getting 0 right now because `%f` is the format specifier for a floating-point value. However, you're passing an integer. Because of the way the architecture works, floating-point values are passed in a different manner than integers, and so the `%f` format specifier is causing the first item on the floating-point stack to be read. This just happens to be `0` in your case.

Comment: technically correct but the key point is the count is # elements added while capacity is the size of the array that you can add to as Mark Adams pointed out ...

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify. I didn't notice his last sentence where he was saying he expected 12.

Comment: @bryanmac `capacity` is not the maximum size of the array, neither does it have anything to do with the `count` which is based on the number of entries that have been added and removed. `capacity` is only a "hint" for an initial pre-allocation, it may be completely ignored by the class.

Answer (score 3):

Sending `-count` to an instance of `NSArray` (or in this case `NSMutableArray`) doesn't yield the capacity of the array, it actually returns the number of objects in the collection. You can have `-count` return 12 by putting 12 objects into the array.

Comment: The capacity isn't the maximum number of objects allowed; it's just a hint for how much space to preallocate. NSMutableArray's capacity is limited only by your hardware.

Comment: Are you saying that adding more items to an array than it's set capacity won't raise an exception?

Comment: Yep, that's right. As noted in the documentation for `initWithCapacity:`, "Mutable arrays expand as needed; numItems simply establishes the object’s initial capacity." AFAIK it's basically a microoptimization, because NSMutableArray using different underlying representations for arrays of different sizes, so it might save quite a few allocations if you're heavily mutating arrays in a hotspot. I've never seen a case where it made a difference. I always just use `[NSMutableArray array]`, personally.

Comment: Is this some legacy thing? I can't see why this would be necessary on any modern system.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that OP expected the output to match the value of `totalBarCount`, even after only adding 1 object to the array.